# Exceptionless.extras error in VS2015 using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have been programming a web forms application using VS2015.
All of a sudden an error form starts popping up for Exceptionless.Extras has encountered a problem and needs to close.
Then asking me to send to submit a report [Exceptionless.Extras Error dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ10D.png)

To my knowledge I have not added any packages for this control.  Checking Tools and NuGet for Exceptionless shows nothing installed

How do I get rid of this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is happening for me also with VS2015 Community Update 3 (V14.0.25431.01). It makes VS unusable as the dialog is shown frequently. I can't find anything out there on this one. So far all we've been able to do here is start VS in safe mode. Not a great fix but all I've got at the moment. I've added this as a comment instead of an answer because I don't consider this a satisfactory fix.

Comment: Happening here also - super annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith Tools on CodeSmith Generator as well as the Exceptionless Project. This could be caused by an unhandled Visual Studio exception that's being picked up by the CodeSmith Generator add-in or a third party add-in which uses Exceptionless. If you have Generator installed. I'd recommend submitting the exception with your email address and contact support and we'll take a look into the exception. Also, we can let you know how to disable this dialog if you have CodeSmith Generator installed.